# interpreting c++ memory errors on android NDK

Tags: android, c++

I am writing a test using native code on android platform where I am using 40Mb+ of data to test native memory usage. The c++ code and JNI are simple:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_ndktest_MainActivity_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {

    int size = 10000000; //10MB
    int array[size];
    // filling up an array to test memory limits
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }
    string asize = to_string(sizeof(array));


    return env->NewStringUTF(asize.c_str());
}
```

When `size` is less than 10MB, the program works fine however when I increase the memory this error message appears

> 2019-07-03 10:55:19.022 7136-7136/com.example.ndktest A/libc: Fatal
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfd29aeb0 in
>   tid 7136 (m.example.ndktest), pid 7136 (m.example.ndktest)

How can I interpret these error messages? The device I am using has 4Gb of RAM which is more than enough.

Comment: Technically your code is not valid C++ code, since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, especially for very large arrays that could overflow the limited stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how is it variable length if I am setting the size at the start of the function?

Comment: Could be dereferencing a null ptr or a corrupted ptr.

Comment: Because `size` is not a compile-time constant, it's a normal variable that is initialized at run-time (every time the function is called).

Comment: As for the crash, you probably have a stack overflow, as the array doesn't fit the limited stack of the system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Seriously? What a strange language that is ... I understand that you can't change the size dynamically, but heck, creating an array at runtime with a given size ... not being able to do that. Strange ...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changing the std::vector actually worked

Comment: @user7331538 Yes. `std::vector` allocates memory on the heap (which is only bounded by your memory size) as opposed to the stack (which is typically fairly small, as you noticed). As a final remark, 10,000,000 integers take up 40 MB, not 10 MB.